# .htaccess user agents and website security

Tags: security, .htaccess, useragent

I have been looking around and trying to work out the best way to protect a few websites of mine.

Appart from the obvious manual monitoring of the site logs and banning extreme/suspicious activity. I have seen many posts etc. about banning user agents. Is this a good route to go down? and would it be a better idea too, instead off banning known bad user agents, just allowing the common mainstream ones such as IE, FireFox, Safari and Chrome?

http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess13.shtml

Comment: What are you looking to protect from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not worth it.

The User Agent is sent by the client, and is trivial to forge. There's [a Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/) that adds alternate UA options to the menu, for example. If the attacker is writing a script, he can specify whatever UA he wants.

Comment: Indeed, most site suckers give you a list of UAs to impersonate, just so the web server thinks it's dealing with a regular browser.